# TicTacToe Nobody wins AND overriding player's choices

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am a new programmer and i started learning python and wanted to learn to code a tic tac toe game.

The game goes on but the winning conditions and computer field selection do not work properly: it doesn't know when to stop playing and sometimes the computer selects an already selected field, thus overriding my choice (if i try to do the same, i get a ValueError).

For the win algorithm, i didn't want to go through all options by hand, so i used sets. I created a set with all winning conditions. While iterating on each subset (rows, cols and diagonals) i check if this is a subset of player/computer positions.

Problem is: it doesn't work. If i try to do anything i get a *ValueError: list.remove(x) x not in list*. I get this error sometimes on the line where the playerChoice gets removed, or the one from the computer. 
Another problem as stated above is that the computer can override my choice.

I think the problem lies on removing elements from one set and adding them to the other, but i can't find a way to get around this

Here is the code:

```
import random

board = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]
playerSymbol = ""
playerPosition = []
aiSymbol = ""
aiPosition = []
possiblePositions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
turn = 0


def drawBoard():
    print(board[0] + " | " + board[1] + " | " + board[2])
    print("___" + "___" + "___")
    print(board[3] + " | " + board[4] + " | " + board[5])
    print("___" + "___" + "___")
    print(board[6] + " | " + board[7] + " | " + board[8])


def choice():
    global playerSymbol
    global aiSymbol

    answer = input("What do you want to play as? (type x or o) ")

    if answer.upper() == "X":
        playerSymbol = "X"
        aiSymbol = "O"
    else:
        playerSymbol = "O"
        aiSymbol = "X"


def won():
    winningPositions = [{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}, {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}]

    for position in winningPositions:
        if position.issubset(playerPosition):
            print("Player Wins :)")
            return True
        elif position.issubset(aiPosition):
            print("AI wins :(")
            return True
        else:
            return False


def play():
    global turn
    choice()

    while not won():
        if turn % 2 == 0:
            pos = int(input("Where would you like to play? (0-8) "))
            possiblePositions.remove(pos)
            playerPosition.append(pos)
            board[pos] = playerSymbol
            turn += 1
            drawBoard()
        else:
            aiTurn = random.randint(0, len(possiblePositions) - 1)
            possiblePositions.remove(possiblePositions[aiTurn])
            aiPosition.append(aiTurn)
            board[aiTurn] = aiSymbol
            turn += 1
            print("\n")
            print("\n")
            drawBoard()
    else:
        print("Thanks for playing :)")


play()
```

I am open to all sorts of suggestions and ways to improve my code.
Thanks in advance and stay healthy, 
Kristi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. In AI's turn, you're generating "upto the length of available positions". You need to generate "One of available positions".

Change these lines:

```
    aiTurn = random.randint(0, len(possiblePositions) - 1)
    possiblePositions.remove(possiblePositions[aiTurn])
```

to

```
    aiTurn = random.choice(possiblePositions)
    possiblePositions.remove(aiTurn)
```

2. In `won()`, you need to iterate over every possible combination until a comparision eveluates to `True`. However, you return either true or false after just the first comparision. Move the `return False` outside the loop:

Change

```
    for position in winningPositions:
        if position.issubset(playerPosition):
            print("Player Wins :)")
            return True
        elif position.issubset(aiPosition):
            print("AI wins :(")
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

to

```
    for position in winningPositions:
        if position.issubset(playerPosition):
            print("Player Wins :)")
            return True
        elif position.issubset(aiPosition):
            print("AI wins :(")
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: I implemented it and it worked thanks :) I would have used the .choice function much much earlier if i knew about it

Answer (score 0):

At first, it's better to print the whole temp field and field with input number, because it's uncomfortable to choose box from 0-8. Make like this, it's really easy to understand(for example):

```
[ ][ ][X]    [1][2][3]
[ ][ ][0]    [4][5][6]
[X][0][X]    [7][8][9]
Choose you box.
```

At second, you must check this line

```
aiTurn = random.randint(0, len(possiblePositions) - 1)
```

You doesn't check the random value, but it can be later move. Because of this ai can choose not empty field. Make like this:

```
#for example
if aiTurn in PosiblePositions:
    make_move()
else:
    generate_new_move()
```

At third, when you try to remove a value, which is not in list, it cause ValueEror:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a.remove(4)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

- In `play()`, `aiTurn` is an index to a board position in `possiblePositions`, so you should do something like `pos = possiblePositions[aiTurn]`, THEN `possiblePositions.remove(pos)`, `aiPosition.append(pos)` and `board[pos] = aiSymbol`.  Right now you're mixing board position and index.
- This might be a confusing way to encode things though, IMHO it'd be better to just maintain the board (no lists of player/ai positions), and base `win()` off this.  For example, initialize `board = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, then set `board[pos] = 1` for X's and `board[pos] = -1` for O's.  Then your `win()` can check rows/cols/diags for anything that sums to 3 or -3.
- If you do it this way, it will take a tiny bit more work to get the computer's move, something like `pos = random.choice([i for i,p in enumerate(board) if p==0])` .. but it will save you work elsewhere
- You need some logic to account for draws/cats game
- I think the use of `global` here is unnecessary, those variables already have global scope and should be accessible within each function.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It does :) I hadn't thought of that coding before, but i suppose it might come in handy when making it look better

Comment: by the way: what would you suggest for a draw? I tried the condition of the entire field being occupied (len(possiblePositions) == 0), but it does't help if i win on the last move, as it still shows a tie...please help